# .htaccess password protection not working in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, htpasswd

I tried to implement htaccess password protection for a directory in my localhost.

My htaccess file is situated in `/home/Server/Dev`. The directory I want to protect is `/Dev/`. My .htaccess file has the following contents:-

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/admin/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

My .htpasswd file is situated in `/home/admin/.htpasswd` and has the following content:-

```
sparky:19m8GEYhMZvMY
```

But when I try accessing `http://localhost/Dev/`, password is not asked and the url is directly accessible. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely be because you have an [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) statement that is disallowing access to .htaccess files. You will need to configure as a minimum

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

within a `<Directory>` block for  `/home/Server/Dev`

```
<Directory /home/Server/Dev >
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added `AllowOverride AuthConfig` to `000-default' within a <Directory> block for `/home/Server/Dev`. Now the username-password window is shown, but no matter what I enter, a 500 internal server error page is shown when i click login.

Comment: Then you should go and look at your apache error log for more .information

Comment: Whoever finds this online, don't forget to add `ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"` because otherwise it will throw you into an endless loop if you don't get the password right